# How to get PK info from SQL Server Compact

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

My company is using SQL Server Compact to store and manage a local database and I need to get the primary key information from the database tables.

I have used `OleDbConnection.GetSchema()` in the past to get this information from Access databases using Jet and OLE drivers. But it appears that `SqlCeConnection.GetSchema()` throws a `NotImplementedException` (or rather that it returns `DBConnection.GetSchema()` which throws the same exception).

I don't need all of the information normally returned by `GetSchema()`, just the names of the PK's. Is there a good way to find out the Primary Key for a table in a SQL Server Compact database?

**NOTE:** The above method references are not static function calls. Consider the class name to be an object reference of that type.

Comment: GetSchema works fine with SQL Compact 4.0!

Comment: @ErikEJ:  Thanks, I might need that in the future.  I'll upgrade when I get the chance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT INDEX_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES
  WHERE PRIMARY_KEY = 1
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable';
```

Comment: I think the view name is different, but this is how it is done :)

Comment: @leppie I suspected so, but can't seem to find any documentation on the schema on MSDN. Will update when I find it.

Comment: You can see it SSMS though, under views :) I have used it a lot in a past project.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: +1 for the different way of thinking.  I got so locked into expecting the Object to do it for me that I neglected the intelligence in the Database itself.  I'm looking at it now and will update your answer with the final SQL statement.  If I can get it to work I'll mark as answer.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Added the correct syntax and marked as answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: I think it's funny that they chose `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for metadata and that there is a single `sys` view exposed (`sys.lock_information`). Guess I'm glad I stay away from Compact. :-)